# Error while installing Rails on Mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

After I install Rails and I run `rails server` for a cloned repository that runs on RoR I see:

> Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:
>
> ```
> $ sudo gem install rails
> ```
>
> You can then rerun your "rails" command.

Right before this I installed Rails which according to terminal was correctly installed.
The command I had run was `sudo gem install rails -V`. To which I get:

```
HEAD https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
HEAD https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
200 OK
GET https://rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz
200 OK
HEAD https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
HEAD https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz
200 OK
GET https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz
302 Moved Temporarily
GET https://s3.amazonaws.com/production.s3.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz
200 OK
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/README.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/akshaysurve.jpg
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/belongs_to.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/book_icon.gif
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/bullet.gif
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/chapters_icon.gif
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/check_bullet.gif
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/credits_pic_blank.gif
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/csrf.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/edge_badge.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/favicon.ico
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/feature_tile.gif
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/footer_tile.gif
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/fxn.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/getting_started/challenge.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/getting_started/confirm_dialog.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/getting_started/forbidden_attributes_for_new_post.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/getting_started/form_with_errors.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/getting_started/index_action_with_edit_link.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/getting_started/new_post.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/getting_started/post_with_comments.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/getting_started/rails_welcome.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/getting_started/routing_error_no_controller.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/getting_started/routing_error_no_route_matches.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/getting_started/show_action_for_posts.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/getting_started/template_is_missing_posts_new.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/getting_started/undefined_method_post_path.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/getting_started/unknown_action_create_for_posts.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/getting_started/unknown_action_new_for_posts.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/grey_bullet.gif
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/habtm.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/has_many.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/has_many_through.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/has_one.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/has_one_through.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/header_backdrop.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/header_tile.gif
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/i18n/demo_html_safe.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/i18n/demo_localized_pirate.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/i18n/demo_translated_en.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/i18n/demo_translated_pirate.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/i18n/demo_translation_missing.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/i18n/demo_untranslated.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/1.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/10.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/11.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/12.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/13.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/14.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/15.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/2.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/3.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/4.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/5.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/6.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/7.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/8.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/icons/callouts/9.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/icons/caution.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/icons/example.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/icons/home.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/icons/important.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/icons/next.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/icons/note.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/icons/prev.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/icons/README
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/icons/tip.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/icons/up.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/icons/warning.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/jaimeiniesta.jpg
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/nav_arrow.gif
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/oscardelben.jpg
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/polymorphic.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/radar.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/rails4_features.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/rails_guides_kindle_cover.jpg
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/rails_guides_logo.gif
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/rails_logo_remix.gif
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/session_fixation.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/tab_grey.gif
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/tab_info.gif
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/tab_note.gif
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/tab_red.gif
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/tab_yellow.gif
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/tab_yellow.png
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/images/vijaydev.jpg
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/javascripts/guides.js
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/javascripts/jquery.min.js
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/javascripts/responsive-tables.js
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/javascripts/syntaxhighlighter/shBrushAppleScript.js
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/javascripts/syntaxhighlighter/shBrushAS3.js
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/javascripts/syntaxhighlighter/shBrushBash.js
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/javascripts/syntaxhighlighter/shBrushColdFusion.js
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/javascripts/syntaxhighlighter/shBrushCpp.js
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/javascripts/syntaxhighlighter/shBrushCSharp.js
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/javascripts/syntaxhighlighter/shBrushCss.js
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/javascripts/syntaxhighlighter/shBrushDelphi.js
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/javascripts/syntaxhighlighter/shBrushDiff.js
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/javascripts/syntaxhighlighter/shBrushErlang.js
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/javascripts/syntaxhighlighter/shBrushGroovy.js
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/javascripts/syntaxhighlighter/shBrushJava.js
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/javascripts/syntaxhighlighter/shBrushJavaFX.js
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/javascripts/syntaxhighlighter/shBrushJScript.js
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/javascripts/syntaxhighlighter/shBrushPerl.js
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/javascripts/syntaxhighlighter/shBrushPhp.js
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/javascripts/syntaxhighlighter/shBrushPlain.js
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/javascripts/syntaxhighlighter/shBrushPowerShell.js
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/javascripts/syntaxhighlighter/shBrushPython.js
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/javascripts/syntaxhighlighter/shBrushRuby.js
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/javascripts/syntaxhighlighter/shBrushSass.js
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/javascripts/syntaxhighlighter/shBrushScala.js
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/javascripts/syntaxhighlighter/shBrushSql.js
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/javascripts/syntaxhighlighter/shBrushVb.js
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/javascripts/syntaxhighlighter/shBrushXml.js
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/javascripts/syntaxhighlighter/shCore.js
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/stylesheets/fixes.css
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/stylesheets/kindle.css
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/stylesheets/main.css
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/stylesheets/print.css
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/stylesheets/reset.css
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/stylesheets/responsive-tables.css
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/stylesheets/style.css
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/stylesheets/syntaxhighlighter/shCore.css
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/stylesheets/syntaxhighlighter/shCoreDefault.css
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/stylesheets/syntaxhighlighter/shCoreDjango.css
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/stylesheets/syntaxhighlighter/shCoreEclipse.css
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/stylesheets/syntaxhighlighter/shCoreEmacs.css
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/stylesheets/syntaxhighlighter/shCoreFadeToGrey.css
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/stylesheets/syntaxhighlighter/shCoreMDUltra.css
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/stylesheets/syntaxhighlighter/shCoreMidnight.css
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/stylesheets/syntaxhighlighter/shCoreRDark.css
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/stylesheets/syntaxhighlighter/shThemeDefault.css
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/stylesheets/syntaxhighlighter/shThemeDjango.css
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/stylesheets/syntaxhighlighter/shThemeEclipse.css
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/stylesheets/syntaxhighlighter/shThemeEmacs.css
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/stylesheets/syntaxhighlighter/shThemeFadeToGrey.css
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/stylesheets/syntaxhighlighter/shThemeMDUltra.css
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/stylesheets/syntaxhighlighter/shThemeMidnight.css
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/stylesheets/syntaxhighlighter/shThemeRailsGuides.css
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/assets/stylesheets/syntaxhighlighter/shThemeRDark.css
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/bug_report_templates/action_controller_gem.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/bug_report_templates/action_controller_master.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/bug_report_templates/active_record_gem.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/bug_report_templates/active_record_master.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/CHANGELOG.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/app/assets/javascripts/application.js
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/app/assets/javascripts/comments.js.coffee
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/app/assets/javascripts/posts.js.coffee
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/app/assets/javascripts/welcome.js.coffee
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/app/assets/stylesheets/comments.css.scss
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/app/assets/stylesheets/posts.css.scss
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/app/assets/stylesheets/welcome.css.scss
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/app/controllers/application_controller.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/app/helpers/application_helper.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/app/helpers/comments_helper.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/app/helpers/posts_helper.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/app/helpers/welcome_helper.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/app/models/comment.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/app/models/post.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/app/views/comments/_comment.html.erb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/app/views/comments/_form.html.erb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/app/views/posts/_form.html.erb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/app/views/posts/edit.html.erb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/app/views/posts/index.html.erb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/app/views/posts/new.html.erb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/app/views/posts/show.html.erb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/app/views/welcome/index.html.erb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/bin/bundle
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/bin/rails
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/bin/rake
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/config/application.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/config/boot.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/config/database.yml
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/config/environment.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/config/environments/development.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/config/environments/production.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/config/environments/test.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/config/initializers/inflections.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/config/initializers/locale.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/config/initializers/mime_types.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/config/initializers/secret_token.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/config/initializers/session_store.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/config/locales/en.yml
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/config/routes.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/config.ru
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/db/migrate/20130122042648_create_posts.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/db/migrate/20130122045842_create_comments.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/db/schema.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/db/seeds.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/Gemfile
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/Gemfile.lock
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/public/404.html
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/public/422.html
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/public/500.html
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/public/favicon.ico
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/public/robots.txt
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/Rakefile
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/README.rdoc
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/test/controllers/comments_controller_test.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/test/controllers/posts_controller_test.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/test/controllers/welcome_controller_test.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/test/fixtures/comments.yml
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/test/fixtures/posts.yml
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/test/helpers/comments_helper_test.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/test/helpers/posts_helper_test.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/test/helpers/welcome_helper_test.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/test/models/comment_test.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/test/models/post_test.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/code/getting_started/test/test_helper.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/rails_guides/generator.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/rails_guides/helpers.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/rails_guides/indexer.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/rails_guides/kindle.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/rails_guides/levenshtein.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/rails_guides/markdown/renderer.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/rails_guides/markdown.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/rails_guides.rb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/Rakefile
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/2_2_release_notes.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/2_3_release_notes.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/3_0_release_notes.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/3_1_release_notes.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/3_2_release_notes.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/4_0_release_notes.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/_license.html.erb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/_welcome.html.erb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/action_controller_overview.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/action_mailer_basics.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/action_view_overview.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/active_model_basics.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/active_record_basics.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/active_record_callbacks.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/active_record_querying.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/active_record_validations.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/active_support_core_extensions.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/active_support_instrumentation.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/api_documentation_guidelines.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/asset_pipeline.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/association_basics.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/caching_with_rails.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/command_line.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/configuring.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/contributing_to_ruby_on_rails.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/credits.html.erb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/debugging_rails_applications.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/development_dependencies_install.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/documents.yaml
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/engines.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/form_helpers.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/generators.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/getting_started.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/i18n.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/index.html.erb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/initialization.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/kindle/copyright.html.erb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/kindle/KINDLE.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/kindle/layout.html.erb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/kindle/rails_guides.opf.erb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/kindle/toc.html.erb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/kindle/toc.ncx.erb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/kindle/welcome.html.erb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/layout.html.erb
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/layouts_and_rendering.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/maintenance_policy.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/migrations.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/nested_model_forms.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/plugins.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/rails_application_templates.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/rails_on_rack.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/routing.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/ruby_on_rails_guides_guidelines.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/security.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/testing.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/source/working_with_javascript_in_rails.md
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/rails-4.0.1/guides/w3c_validator.rb
Successfully installed rails-4.0.1
Parsing documentation for rails-4.0.1
Parsing sources...
100% [260/260]  guides/w3c_validator.rb
Done installing documentation for rails after 2 seconds
1 gem installed
```

Where am I wrong? I have Ruby 2.0.0 installed on my machine.

Comment: Ruby 4.0? Good choice

Comment: a typo, its ruby 2.0.0

Comment: Maybe you removed rails binary when uninstalling an older version of Rails, or your $PATH doesn't include your rails binary.

Comment: That's a strange error...  What happens if you run `rails -v`?  Also, you probably want to consider some kind of Ruby version manager (rbenv, rvm, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I sorted it out myself, though the tough way as the railsinstaller doesn't work with Mavericks. Firstly, I uninstalled both rvm and homebrew doing that I accidentally deleted the ruby folder from my /User/bin folder too which deleted the default ruby package.

Now, I downloaded the source code from ruby-lang decompressed it and did a

```
./configure
make test
make install
```

which installed the package correctly. Since it was rvm, homebrew and macport clashing, I moved out the macport and used brew to upgrade my ruby install and finally download rails via

```
gem install rails
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you let us know what this returns?

```
which rails
```

You should see something like this:

```
/Users/<user>/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin
```

I am assuming you just need to update your PATH with the path to `rails`.

Make sure that you have something like this at the end of your login script (bash_login, etc):

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

This will ensure rvm is in your path.

Do you have to use `sudo` to install `rails`?  If not, I would try installing without `sudo`.

Comment: it returns /usr/bin/rails

Comment: I have both rvm and brew installations of ruby, can that be a problem? (Just guessing)

Comment: Is this a Mac? or Linux? Macs also come with ruby pre-installed.  I would definitely `brew uninstall ruby` and make sure that your bash login script includes the rvm script.

Answer (score 0):

Install xcode before installing rails on your mac.